# Find index in a list using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, replace, syntax

Again I'm having trouble with the syntax of Python (Using Python 3)

```
f=["-5","-4","-3","-2","-1","0","1","2","3","4","5"]
print(f.index('-'))
```

what I'm I doing wrong with it because it is giving me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 4, in <module>
ValueError: '-' is not in list
```

?

I need the index in a list or an array to replace the negative sign with M I might need help with the replace code as well.

Comment: What are you trying to do.. ?  list.index is for exact match?   do you want to check the wildcard or the first occurrence ?

Comment: just trying to find - negative sign soon answered it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is very clear. No element of the **list `f`** equals **-**. If you want to get the index of any element in `f`, you should use the `list.index` method as demonstrated below.

```
f=["-5","-4","-3","-2","-1","0","1","2","3","4","5"]
f.index("0")

>>> 5
```

The index of the element "0" in `f` is **5**. That is **"0"** is the **sixth** element of `f`.

If you want to replace every occurrence of **"-"** with **M** in `f`, you can either use any of the two methods suggested by @soon and @Anthony or you can use **regular expressions** and **list comprehension**. I have also attached some code.

```
import re
[re.sub('-', 'M', x) for x in f]

>>> ['M5', 'M4', 'M3', 'M2', 'M1', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

I think it would be helpful to look at [this w3Schools Tutotial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_index.asp) on **list index**.

Comment: thanks for the assistance. I will looking the w3Schools

Answer (score 0):

`list.index` searches for exact match. If you want to replace negative sign with M for all elements, you can iterate over the list and call `str.replace` for each element:

```
In [14]: f=["-5","-4","-3","-2","-1","0","1","2","3","4","5"]

In [15]: [x.replace('-', 'M') for x in f]
Out[15]: ['M5', 'M4', 'M3', 'M2', 'M1', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since accepted answer uses list comprehension, the code below is the same but with a simple For loop.

```
f=["-5","-4","-3","-2","-1","0","1","2","3","4","5"]

for i, x in enumerate(f):
    f[i] = x.replace("-","M")

print(f)
```

Note: This will only work if your list only contains strings.